# how to sort randomly scattered points according to the region

Tags: c++, sorting, graphics, 2d

Im very new to c++ and only know the very basics. array, if while for dynamic and pointer..

I am working on a code and here is what i want to do.
For example on a 2D square plane(10x10) I have randomly scattered 1000 points(an array of size 100). 
The 2D square plane is divided into 10 smaller rectangles. Now I want to sort the 1000 points into these smaller rectangles. Basically, I want to make 10 dynamic arrays(one for each "small rectangle") and each of these array will contain the scattered points that are inside the corresponding region.

The most basic iteration i thought of was just use if, if, if...
But with this, I have to repeat the iteration 1000times for each region. And I think it is very inefficient.

Comment: A. A square plain of `10x10` has a 1000 points? can there be more than one point in each location. B. In what format are the 1000 points kept? How are the regions represented?

Comment: Are these divisions regular?  Do they cover the entire space?  Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function to classify a single point, i.e. determine into which region it belongs. As a simple example that you can expand:

```
std::size_t classify(double px, double py, double split) {
 if (px < split) {
  return 0; // left plane
 } else {
  return 1; // right plane
 }
}
```

Then, iterate over the points and put them into respective containers:

```
std::vector<std::vector<point_t>> region{2};
for (auto const & point : points) {
 region[classify(point.x, point.y, split)].push_back(point);
}
```

This way you iterate once over all points, doing a classification (that should be possible to do in constant time in your case) for every point, which is the minimum work required.